# Eliminating the Occurence of junk Values in an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I am getting an XML in the below mentioned Format....

```
<META NAME="ColdFusionMXEdition" CONTENT="ColdFusion DevNet Edition - Not for Production Use."> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ParticipantService>
<Response>
    <FileName>Alzheimers</FileName>
    <playlist>
        <question answer="t" qno="1" tin="113" title="Aide responds" tout="114"/>
        <question answer="t" qno="2" tin="123" title="Receptionist reports problem" tout="126"/>
        <question answer="t" qno="3" tin="127" title="Receptionist objects to restraint" tout="130"/>
.............
```

I am storing the above mentioned XML in the form of an NSString. Now i just want to capture the data starting from

```
<?xml version="1.0".......
```

From here i want to Parse the String which doesnt contain the META Tag characters. Can someone please post any alternative here?

Comment: What happens if you just throw it at NSXMLPArser?

Comment: U cant Parse the String which contains Junk Values before the "<xml.... " tag. So i need to definitely parse the string value which starts definitely with the standard XML Tag(i.e.. <?xml version="1.0".......)

Comment: you can remove the unwanted string from your xml string, only keep the string starting from <xml ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) has plenty of methods to work with.  Here's my solution which is similar to Peter's:

```
NSString *newString = [xmlString substringFromIndex:[xmlString rangeOfString:@"<?xml"].location];
```

or if you already have an NSMutableString:

```
[mutableXMLString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [mutableXMLString rangeOfString:@"<?xml"].location)];
```

Of course, neither solution tackles cases where there isn't any `<?xml`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
NSString *parseString = [xmlString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([xmlString rangeOfString: @"<?xml"].location, ([xmlString length] - [xmlString rangeOfString: @"<?xml"].location))];
```